# Filter string date time in MongoDB returns nothing

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to get the data from the Azure CosmosDB MongoDB older than yesterday. The property date is string `"2022-08-03T13:12:24.455271"`. The below code returns nothing.

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
var page = 1;
var limit = 10;
var subfilter = new BsonDocument("$expr",
new BsonDocument("$lte",
        new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument("$toDate", "$upload_time"), date
        }
    )
);

var value = await collection.Find(subfilter).Skip((page - 1) * limit).Limit(limit).ToListAsync();
```

Using Mongosh I can retrieve the data using this

```
db.uploads.find({"$expr": {"$lte": [{ "$toDate": "$upload_time" }, ISODate("2022-08-03T00:00:00Z")]}}).skip(0).limit(2)
```

The count of `value` above is always zero, means it failed to get the data.
If the `upload_time` is not `string` then it will be easily using:

```
var value = await collection.Find(w => w.upload_time < date).Skip((page - 1) * limit).Limit(limit).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hmm, what if you run the query without the C# code (for example in MongoDB Compass), do you able to retrieve the data? Suspect that due to the timezone from the input date.

Comment: `DateTime.Today` is your local time. I suppose that MongoDB will interpret your date string (without a timezone) to be UTC. Can it be that UTC vs local time leads to the missing data? You could use `$dateFromString` to convert the string. This has some more options on the format and timezone.